# Check if Chocolatey Package is Install or Upgrade

Tags: installation, chocolatey

Is there any way, within the chocolateyinstall.ps1 file, to check if the process was triggered with the Upgrade command versus the Install command?

I tried using things like "choco list --lo" and "choco outdated", but those kept bringing up the package currently being installed - even if it hadn't yet been fully installed. I was hoping there was some sort of environment variable or something easy that I've overlooked.

Thanks!